# Getting a count of the number of sent SMS messages

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to count the number of sent SMS messages, and when messages are over the limit for 1 message, make them count as 2 (or more).

```
Uri allMessages = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(allMessages, null, null, null, null);
int totalMessages = 0;


while (c.getPosition() < numberRows - 1) 
{
    c.moveToNext();

    //Problem Code
    String messageBody = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
    long messageLength = messageBody.length();
    double numberOfMessages = messageLength / 160;
    double numberOfMessagesRoundedUp = Math.ceil(numberOfMessages);
    //Problem Code


    totalMessages = (int) (totalMessages + numberOfMessagesRoundedUp);
}

c.close();
```

Apart from something in the 4 lines marked above, the code works fine. I'm attempting to read the body of each text and get the length, and then divide by 160 (the SMS limit) and round up to the nearest integer, giving me the number of messages used. The code gives far too small a value, about 50 times less than it should be.

Comment: No, it runs fine and worked when I wasn't trying to count longer messages as 2 or more.

Comment: change 160 to 160.0. See my code below.

Comment: I explain how to count the number of sent smses here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76321264/12534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 160 tot 160.0 to get the value behind the dot, else it will return like an integer.

Also you can change the while loop with the following.

```
while (c.moveToNext()) 
{
    String messageBody = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
    long messageLength = messageBody.length();
    double numberOfMessages = messageLength / 160.0;
    double numberOfMessagesRoundedUp = Math.ceil(numberOfMessages);

    totalMessages = (int) (totalMessages + numberOfMessagesRoundedUp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whilst a single SMS is up to 160 characters, a message that uses multiple SMSes to send can only put 153 characters in a message. (The other characters are used to specify 'this is sms number x of y in this multi-part message.') So, in psuedo code:

```
 if (numCharsThisMessage <= 160) numSMSthisMessage = 1;
 else numSMSthisMessage = 1 + (numChars-1)/153; // -1 because 0-153 is message 1, 154-307 is next ...

 totalSMSsent += numSMSthisMessage;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting, makes sense but could you provide a source? I'd like to check this out before I update my app! Thanks.

Comment: Well, I worked it out by watching how my phone (HTC desire) determined how many SMS were needed for a given size message. Afraid I don't have a formal reference, it seemed sensible to mimic what the phone did!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out... replace your while loop with below

```
while (c.moveToNext();) 
{

String messageBody = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
long messageLength = messageBody.length();
int numberOfMessages =(int )(messageLength / 160);
totalMessages += numberOfMessages+1;

}
```