# How to count SMS segments?

Tags: sms, gsm

In the SMS specification, it can deliver messages of 160 characters at once.

That means, if I try to send over 160 (e.g. 161) it is split into two SMSes automatically, then delivered to receiver.

But, nowadays phones don't show 2 messages. It just shows up as 1 message.

It looks like there's some header to represent message identity and it's assembled automatically in the phone.

BTW, is there any way know about SMS header info and how many messages a really delivered/received?

My smartphone (nexus-5) doesn't show it.

Answer (score 2):

These are the axioms we should start with:

1. An sms message (called "user data") can contain 140 bytes exactly
2. Messages are encoded with either 7-bit [GSM 03.38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) or [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (you can think of UTF-16 as UCS-2 extended with support for emojis)
3. If the message contains *any* character that is not in GSM 03.38, UTF-16 will be used for the whole message
4. When [concatenating multiple smses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS), each sms gets a 6-byte [user data header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38), so they can now only contain 134 bytes of message text

So, the code to calculate the number of sms segments or parts for a message could be something like this:

```cs
var messageByteSize = CalculateMessageByteSizeDependingOnEncoding(message);
if (messageByteSize > 140)
{
    // We round up, so that 1.1 parts become 2 parts
    return (int)Math.Ceiling(messageByteSize / 134.0);
}
else
{
    return 1;
}
```

To determine which encoding will be used, check if all the characters are present in [the GSM 03.38 character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7-bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_/_GSM_03.38). If so, that encoding will be used for the whole message. Otherwise, UTF-16 will be used for the whole message.

#### GSM 03.38

Characters in GSM 03.38 are stored as *septets* and take 7 bits (remember, one byte is 8 bits).

Some characters, however, are escaped with an invisible character, and therefore take 2 septets: `|^€{}[]~\`.

To get the total number of septets for a message, you count the total number of characters (both escaped and non-escaped), and then add the number of escaped characters. This will count the escaped characters twice.

The number of bytes is then `septets * 7.0 / 8.0`, which gives that 160 septets is 140 bytes.

In 140 bytes, you can fit 160 unescaped characters (1 septet per character) or 80 escaped characters (2 septets per character).

#### UTF-16

Each UTF-16 character takes up either 2 or 4 bytes, depending on whether the character exists in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) or the Supplementary Multilingual Plane (SMP; all the emojis are here).

You can calculate the total bytes for a UTF-16 string like this, using C#: `Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(message)`.

For Javascript, it's as easy as this: `message.length * 2`, since [String.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) returns the number of UTF-16 "code units", and each such code unit takes 2 bytes.

In 140 bytes, you can fit 70 characters from the BMP (2 bytes per character) or 35 characters from the SMP (4 bytes per character).

Answer (score 1):

SMS is not just delivering 160 characters(1120 bits / (7 bits/character) = 160 characters) for every each time.

If it segmented, it can deliver only 153 characters.
(http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/04/20/concatenated-sms-messages-and-character-counts/)

```
Nc = Total number of characters in message
Nx = Characters from extended GSM table (|^{}[]~\ and euro)
L = Message length in 7-bit characters
M = Number of messages

L = Nc + Nx
L > 160:  M = L / 153 [rounded up]
L <= 160: M = 1
```

The division by 153 is because when sms's are divided into parts, each part gets a header of 48 bits.