# How to Calculate SMS message segments in typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have an Angular 5 application and I have a text area input in one of my component html, where the user can type in various characters. I would like to calculate the message segment count from the user entered characters . 
Any idea how I can do it?

There is this post [Calculate SMS Length/Parts C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801074/calculate-sms-length-parts-c-sharp), however I am not able to convert the code to typescript.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42710344/863110) could help. It's not in typescript but the difference here between javascript and typescript is negligible.

Comment: its showing forbidden bitwise operation .
 export const smsSegmentCalculator = (text:string):number  => {

let byteLen = 0;

for(let i=0;i<text.length;i++){
    const characterCodeAtIndex = text.charCodeAt(i);
        byteLen +=  characterCodeAtIndex < (1 <<  7) ? 1 :
        characterCodeAtIndex < (1 << 11) ? 2 :
        characterCodeAtIndex < (1 << 16) ? 3 :
        characterCodeAtIndex < (1 << 21) ? 4 :
        characterCodeAtIndex < (1 << 26) ? 5 :
        characterCodeAtIndex < (1 << 31) ? 6 : Number.NaN;
    }
return parseInt(byteLen)*8;
}

Comment: What do you mean `its`? Who is `its?

Comment: @Mosh Feu  in my vss code editor it is showing the error [tslint] Forbidden bitwise operation

Comment: Where did you get the code you posted in the comment?

Comment: i changed the code to typescript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196152/discussion-between-knowledgeseeker-and-mosh-feu).

Comment: Ok. And if you [ignore tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/) is it working?

Comment: I would like to add that the code in the related question doesn't work for all characters in messages, so it's probably not the best idea to copy it!